# Objects of data source in UITableViewController become nil after scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, properties, null

For learning purposes in Objective-C, I created an iOS application with core-data and a table view.

I want to read some "Planets" from core data and show them in a table view. The planets from the core-data database are copied directly to the datasource of the ui table. After scrolling in the table, the planet's name's become nil.

Planet.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface Planet : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* system;
@end
```

Planet.m:

```
#import "Planet.h"

@implementation Planet
@dynamic name;
@dynamic system;
@end
```

Custom cell (.h/.m):

```
@interface Cell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
@end

@implementation Cell
@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize textLabel;
@end
```

In the view controller, I read the planets from core-data

```
// core data
AppDelegate *delegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
NSPersistentContainer *container = [delegate persistentContainer];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [container viewContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName: @"Planet"];
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error: nil];

tableViewController.dataSource = [NSArray arrayWithArray: results];
[tableViewController.tableView reloadData];
```

Implementation of tableviewcontroller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString* cellIdentifier = @"cell";

Cell* cell = (Cell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[Cell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier];
    [cell setSelectionStyle: UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
}

Planet* planet = (Planet*) dataSource[indexPath.row];

if(planet != nil) {
    NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] init];

    if(planet.name != nil) {
        name = planet.name;
    } else {
        name = @"name nil";
    }

    [cell.textLabel setText: name];
} else {
    [cell.textLabel setText: @"planet nil"];
}

[cell.imageView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"planet"]];

return cell;
```

}

The result is, that after scrolling the text label displays 'name nil'... The properties of the object's become nil... And I don't know why... When I fill the datasource only with NSString's, the values dont'disappear!

Comment: Show how `dataSource` is declared.

Comment: Declaration of dataSource: @property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *dataSource;

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. The way I get (and save) objects from core data (and to core data) was wrong.

Getting objects from core data:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName: @"Planet"];
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest: request error: nil];

if([results count] == 0) {
    dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0;i < [results count];i++) {
        NSString* name = [results[i] valueForKey: @"name"];
        NSString* system = [results[i] valueForKey: @"system"];

        [dataSource addObject: [Planet planetWithParameters: name : system]];
    }
}
```

Write objects to core data:

```
NSManagedObject *newObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Planet" inManagedObjectContext: context];
[newObject setValue: planets[i] forKey: @"name"];
[newObject setValue: systems[i] forKey: @"system"];
[delegate saveContext];
```